# Foundation Button right

Tags: css, button, zurb-foundation

I would like to have the button positioned on the right. With the code the button is no longer in the fieldset "callout"

```
< button type="button" class="success button">Save</ button>
```

[image]

```
< button type="button" class="success button float-right">Save</ button>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the HTML for the form in the question and indicate which version of foundation you are using and any information about additional frameworks you might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the class `clearfix` on a wrapper around the button or on its current parent element.

See https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/float-classes.html

You can see the difference at https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/QzmgJR